# What can a malicious device on PCIe bus do?

Tags: hardware, firmware

What threat does a malicious device or a device with malicious firmware on a PCIe bus pose?
Can such device access to RAM(only read or write)? All devices on PCIe can have that access(network card, or another)?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? More context would be helpful.

Comment: PCI has access to memory (DMA). PCI network cards can change what gets transmitted or received. Controllers in PCI SSD can infect any stored files... - anything can be done on this deep level of access to the system.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Isn't PCIe device access to memory through DMA limited by IOMMU/VT-D, if present? Not all hardware supports this of course, but the situation is not hopeless.